# Where can I find what SQL dialect that MarkLogic TDE based SQL support?

Tags: sql, marklogic, tde, marklogic-10

MarkLogic TDE enables SQL 'like' access to the document data.
Hence via common ODBC driver, other BI tools could possibly access ML DB in a 'relation db' way. However the challenge I have is to know which SQL dialet ML supports.

For example, I want to find how to find the first 10 records to get a snippet of the data. I could do that with

```
select top 10 * from book (ms sql)
```

or

```
select * from book where rownum <= 10 (oracle sql)
```

How to do the same with MarkLogic SQL?

There are actually many such types of sql syntax questions. I need to find the equivalent of what I normally used with ms sql.
Is there a wiki page to show the difference between ML SQL and MS SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In general, MarkLogic supports the syntax from the [SQL92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

[Supported SQL Statements, Functions and Types](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_89115)

> This section describes the SQL statements and functions supported in MarkLogic. The topics are:
>
> - [Supported Statements](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_60306)
> - [Supported Functions](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_97459)
> - [Supported Types](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/SQLqueries#id_32736)